# BouncyCastle ClassNotFoundException on deployment to WildFly

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, bouncycastle, classnotfoundexception

I want to use the BouncyCastle APIs (v 1.52) to hash passwords with the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1-alogrithm in a web application on a WildFly server. But always when I'm deploying my application I get a "ClassNotFoundException org.bouncycastle.crypto.PBEParametersGenerator" from the server.  I'm using Eclipse Mars and WildFly 8.2.0 and 9.0.1. I don't get any error in my project in Eclipse. I already tried to add the BouncyCastle JARs to my Classpath as described in another topic here but it didn't help. I was wondering why I can't find any other results here or on google about this problem, can anyone help me? I know that Java 8 has a PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256-implementation but nevertheless I want to use BouncyCastle APIs as an alternative.

Here is a very simple example of a project that produces the described error:

BouncyCastleHasher.java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.PBEParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;

@ManagedBean
public class BouncyCastleHasher {
    private String input;
    private String output;

    public String hash() {
        if(input!=null) {
            byte[] salt = "12345678".getBytes();
            PBEParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator();
            generator.init(PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToUTF8Bytes(input.toCharArray()), salt, 1);
            KeyParameter params = (KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedParameters(128);
            byte[] hash = Arrays.toString(params.getKey()).getBytes();
            String encodedText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
            setOutput(encodedText);
        }
        return "out";
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public void setOutput(String output) {
        this.output = output;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Test_BouncyCastle</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>in.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

in.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Hashing site</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText value="Text to hash:" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h:inputText value="#{bouncyCastleHasher.input}" ></h:inputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:commandButton value="Save"
                        action="#{bouncyCastleHasher.hash}"></h:commandButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

out.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Result</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText value="hashed text:" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bouncyCastleHasher.output}"></h:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
    <h:link outcome="in"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The BouncyCastle libs are contained in the WildFly distribution as JBoss modules.

Please try importing the `org.bouncycastle` module into your application and make sure that no copies of the BouncyCastle libs are included in your WAR, e.g. by using `provided` scope for the BouncyCastle dependencies in your POM.

See [Classloading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) for more details on importing modules.

Comment: project is building, but I still get the same error on deployment. I'm using this dependency: `<dependency>
     <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
     <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
     <version>1.46</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>`